# Convert ctypes code to cython

Tags: python, struct, cython

I'd like to convert some ctypes code to use cython instead, but I'm struggling.
Essentially, the ctypes code:

- copies the contents (floats)  of two lists into C-compatible structs
- sends the structs to my binary via FFI
- receives the structs back (the length is never modified)
- *copies* the contents to two new lists
- sends the structs back across the FFI boundary so their memory can be freed

My ctypes code looks like this so far:

`rlib.h`

```
#ifndef RLIB_H
#define RLIB_H

typedef struct _FFIArray {
  void* data;
  size_t len;
} _FFIArray;

typedef struct _Result_Tuple {
    _FFIArray e;
    _FFIArray n;
} _Result_Tuple;

_Result_Tuple convert_to_bng_threaded(_FFIArray x, _FFIArray y);
void drop_float_array(_FFIArray x, _FFIArray y)

#endif
```

`mylib.pxd`

```
cdef extern from "rlib.h":
    struct _FFIArray:
        void* data
        size_t len

    struct _Result_Tuple:
        _FFIArray e
        _FFIArray n

    cdef _Result_Tuple convert_to_bng_threaded(_FFIArray x, _FFIArray y)
    cdef void drop_float_array(_FFIArray x, _FFIArray y)
```

`util_cython.pyx`

```
import cython
from mylib cimport _FFIArray, convert_to_bng_threaded, drop_float_array

def call_convert_bng(_FFIArray x, _FFIArray y):
    return convert_to_bng_threaded(x, y)

def call_drop_float_array(_FFIArray x, _FFIArray y):
    return drop_float_array(x, y)
```

`setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages

from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext = Extension('util_cython', 
          sources=['util_cython.pyx'],
          libraries=['latlon_bng',],
          library_dirs=['.',],
          include_dirs=['.']
)

extensions = [ext,]

setup(
    name = "util_cython",
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
)
```

I have a few questions about how to proceed:

Firstly, the compilation step is currently failing:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Compiling util_cython.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing util_cython.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
import cython
from mylib cimport _FFIArray, convert_to_bng_threaded, drop_float_array

def call_convert_bng(_FFIArray x, _FFIArray y):
    return convert_to_bng_threaded(x, y)
                                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

util_cython.pyx:5:34: Cannot convert '_Result_Tuple' to Python object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),
  File "/Users/sth/dev/cythonize_test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 912, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/Users/sth/dev/cythonize_test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1034, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: util_cython.pyx
```

Why is Cython failing to convert `_Result_tuple`?

Secondly, how do I define a cython function to accept lists (or arrays; anything that supports `__iter__`), and copy their contents into `_FFIArray` structs, so I can call `call_convert_bng`?

Comment: What do you expect here? I would be surprised if cython would make a python tuple out of your custom struct implicitly.

Comment: @cel I expect someone to tell me how to be explicit about what I need to do to get cython to convert my result?

Comment: this may help, though: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/tuple.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is untested, because I don't have the library code and have had to take some guesses as to how it works. But it should give you an idea as to how you go about it.

I'd start by using a Python array type to store your input/output. Either the [standard library array type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), or numpy arrays. These store the arrays continuously in memory (like C would) and so provided the `_FFIArray` `data` attribute can just be pointed at this memory for input.

```
def convert_bng(double[::1] x, double[::1] y):
  # I'm assuming that the data is double, not float, but it's easy changed
  # here the [::1] promises it's continuous in memory
  cdef _FFIArray x_ffi, y_ffi
  # get a pointer to the data, and cast it to void*
  x_ffi.data = <void*>&x[0]
  x_ffi.len = x.shape[0] # possibly *sizeof(double) - depends on the C api

  # repeat for y
  y_ffi.data = <void*>&y[0]
  y_ffi.len = y.shape[0]

  cdef _Result_Tuple result = convert_to_bng_threaded(x_ffi, y_ffi)

  # get data pointers for the two result arrays
  cdef double* e_ptr = <double*>(result.e.data)
  cdef double* n_ptr = <double*>(result.n.data)
  # now view your output arrays using memoryviews
  # you need to tell it the length (this is how many doubles the contain)
  cdef double[::1] e = <double[:result.e.len:1]>e_ptr
  cdef double[::1] n = <double[:result.n.len:1]>n_ptr

  # create a numpy copy of the two arrays
  import numpy as np
  e_numpy = np.copy(e)
  n_numpy = np.copy(n)

  # you can now free your two returned arrays
  # I assume this is done with drop_float_array
  drop_float_array(result.e,result.n)

  # return as tuple containing two arrays to python
  return e_numpy, n_numpy
```