# How to structure a cython module with many identical function signatures

Tags: python, cython

I've written a Cython module which wraps a foreign C function, and it's working as expected. However, I'd like to wrap the rest of the functions provided by my C binary, which have identical signatures. In Python, I could just do:

```
def boilerplate(func):
    def wrapped_f(c, d):
        # modify x and y, producing mod_c and mod_d
        result = func(mod_c, mod_d)
        # modify foreign function return values, producing final_c, final_d
        return final_c, final_d
    return wrapped_f

@boilerplate
def func_a(a, b)
   return _foreign_func_a(a, b)

@boilerplate
def func_b(a, b)
   return _foreign_func_b(a, b)
```

Is there a similar pattern I can use in Cython, in order to "cythonise" `wrapped_f`, assuming `_foreign_func_a` and its accompanying structs etc. have been `cimport`ed?

However, when I move the generic operations into the decorator:

```
def boilerplate(func):
    def wrapped(double[::1] wlon, double[::1] wlat):
        cdef _FFIArray x_ffi, y_ffi
        x_ffi.data = <void*>&wlon[0]
        x_ffi.len = wlon.shape[0]
        y_ffi.data = <void*>&wlat[0]
        y_ffi.len = wlat.shape[0]
        cdef _Result_Tuple result = func(x_ffi, y_ffi)
        cdef double* eastings_ptr = <double*>(result.e.data)
        cdef double* northings_ptr = <double*>(result.n.data)
        cdef double[::1] e = <double[:result.e.len:1]>eastings_ptr
        cdef double[::1] n = <double[:result.n.len:1]>northings_ptr

        e_numpy = np.copy(e)
        n_numpy = np.copy(n)
        drop_float_array(result.e, result.n)
        return e_numpy, n_numpy
    return wrapped

@boilerplate
def convert_bng(double[::1] lons, double[::1] lats):
    """wrapper around threaded conversion function

    """
    return convert_to_bng_threaded(lons, lats)
```

I get errors when

- trying to convert `x_ffi` and `y_ffi` to `_FFIArray` to Python objects in `wrapped`
- converting Python object `func` to `_Result_Tuple` in `wrapped`
- converting `lons` and `lats` to `_FFI_Array` in `convert_to_bng_threaded`, and
- converting `_Result_Tuple` back to a Python object in `convert_bng_threaded`

Comment: I may be reading it wrong, but it looks like you could be asking one of two things. 1) If you want to avoid writing having to write small, one-line wrapper functions for each foreign function then I don't think you can. 2) If you want to use decorators then Cython supports it and you can do it as written (although it probably won't compile to hugely clean C code).

Comment: @DavidW ah, sorry. I'd be fine writing a load of wrapper functions, to be honest. I didn't know I could use decorators like that in Cython. I'll give it a shot and profile the result…

Comment: @urschei It supports the vast, vast, vast majority of Python code (so it's always worth just giving your code a go). It just may not always manage to translate it to particularly fast C code.

Comment: @davidw Have taken your advice, but getting tripped up between the Python and Cython interactions when moving into and back out of the decorator…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your essential problem (based on your updated question) is that you're trying to wrap a function that takes pure C data types (and thus can only be defined as a `cdef` function, and can be called from Cython but not Python). However, decorators work on Python functions, so it doesn't quite come together.

Fortunately you can do something very similar handling the wrapped function a using C function pointer. You need a slightly different syntax but the idea is very much the same. (For the sake of this answer I'm assuming you are using the definitions of C data types from [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299507/convert-ctypes-code-to-cython), which I think is reasonable)

```
# pass a function pointer in
cdef boilerplate(_Result_Tuple (*func)(_FFIArray, _FFIArray)):
    def wrapped(double[::1] wlon, double[::1] wlat):
        cdef _FFIArray x_ffi, y_ffi
        x_ffi.data = <void*>&wlon[0]
        x_ffi.len = wlon.shape[0]
        y_ffi.data = <void*>&wlat[0]
        y_ffi.len = wlat.shape[0]
        cdef _Result_Tuple result = func(x_ffi, y_ffi)
        cdef double* eastings_ptr = <double*>(result.e.data)
        cdef double* northings_ptr = <double*>(result.n.data)
        cdef double[::1] e = <double[:result.e.len:1]>eastings_ptr
        cdef double[::1] n = <double[:result.n.len:1]>northings_ptr

        e_numpy = np.copy(e)
        n_numpy = np.copy(n)
        drop_float_array(result.e, result.n)
        return e_numpy, n_numpy
    return wrapped

# do this instead of using a decorator syntax
convert_bng = boilerplate(&convert_to_bng_threaded)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your two answers have been more valuable than any of the docs or Cython examples I've read.